# Some help please in understanding a JavaScript function call. Is it a closure or recursive?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3js to Tree Layout to present some data, working result here:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/vV3Sc/

I would like to learn how to correctly navigate the nodes in the tree. So for example I could setup a function to set all nodes to either open/closed with a single click or perhaps have a category index so a visitor could click `year one` and that node and all children would be set to open.

I have stepped through the code and I can't get my head around

```
function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
        toggle(d);
    }
}

root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
```

To me I call the function with the `root` and then if the passed node has `children` for each `child` of that `node` I pass it the function name?! When there are no more `children` i.e. it has reached a `leaf` it toggles the value from `children` to `_children` or the inverse.

What is happening when I'm passing forEach `toggleAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is `forEach`, which is a native javascript function.
(documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

This method executes the callback (`toggleAll`) for each element of the array. 
The `d` parameter will be passed to the `toggleAll` function by `forEach`. So it doesn't come from the closure.

Now since toggleAll calls `forEach` again, it does indeed go into a recursive pattern to the next level of the tree, untill `d.children` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

How did you produce this working code if you do not understand what's happening?

> What is happening when I'm passing it toggleAll?

Do you understand what "it" refers to in this question?

Anyway, you are working with JavaScript arrays (or at least array-like things), you are calling the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, which accepts a function and invokes that function on each of the elements. So when you first call forEach on `root.children`, `toggleAll` is invoked with each element in the array `root.children`. You then call forEach again (recursively now) for any subsequent childnodes.

Comment: I used this demonstration http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html and as you can see I changed the JSON document. I've cleared up my use of "it".